# An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Main.toolStripStatusLabel1'

Tags: c#, object, methods, static

I'm trying to set a `toolStripStatusLabel` from a static method :

```
public static void loggedChanged()
{
    if (SM_Class.logged)
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Conectado: " + SM_Class.logged_user.username;
    else
    {
        toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Desconectado";
    }
}
```

This comes from another static declaration in a class

```
public static Boolean logged
{
    get { return _logged; }
    set
    {
        if (_logged != value)
        {
            _logged = value;
            Main.loggedChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Main.toolStripStatusLabel1'

What shall I change to be able to update the `toolstriplabel`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `toolStripStatusLabel1` should be static as well.

Comment: Thanks. But where should i declare toolstripStatusLabel1 as static? it's now declared like this: private System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1;

Comment: Static initialization runs before some of instance fields. That's why you might net this exceptions. So, make sure that toolStripStatusLabel1 is initialized before you use it

Comment: if i add this declaration i dont get the error:  ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1 = new ToolStripStatusLabel();  - but the toolstripstatuslabel is not displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have only given part of the code, but it looks like the problem is that `loggedChanged` is static but `toolStripStatusLabel1` isn't. Either make the latter static or the former non-static. I'd recommend making both `logged` and `loggedChanged` non-static as making things static without good reason is bad practice.

Comment: thanks a lot. i remove the static declaration from both of them and now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access non-static stuff from a static method, unless you get it passed as an argument.

```
class MyClass{
   String nonstaticField;
   static String staticField;

   static Foo(String obj){
      nonstaticField.Trim(); // no
      staticField.Trim()     // yes
      obj.Trim();            // yes
    }
}
```

So you `toolStripStatusLabel1` must be static as well. Without knowing something more, the best place to have it is just as a static field in the same class it is now.

Comment: thanks a lot. i remove the static declaration from both of them and now it's working fine.